# see or know some one for first time?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-request, difference, verbs

I have a problem  with finding correct verb. for example when you read about a writer for first time, or when you watch a movie and see an actor for first time, which verb we should to use in this sentence?
I just knew him? or, I just see him?
notice that I want to say I just knew that this person is exist!

Comment: "I first saw Russell Crowe in _Gladiator_." or "saw him for the first time". With a writer it would have to be _discovered_ or _first heard of_.

Answer (score 1):

"**I was first introduced to** Stanley Kubrick's films when I was at art college".

"My teacher **introduced me to** classical music".

Note that the use of 'introduced to' is quite formal.

Answer (score 0):

“I know that actor”

“That actor looks familiar”

“I recognize that actor”

“I’m familiar with that actor”

“I know who that is”